# Unity Classes Extract Information

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine

I am quite new to using classes in unity C# and i have a problem. I dont know how to explain it so just follow along:

```
class Table()
{

    int TableHeight;            //variables of the class
    
    string TableName;

    Table(int _TableHeight, string _TableName)  //constructor of class
    {
        TableHeight = _TableHeight;
        TableName = _TableName;
    }

}

public class TableCreator : MonoBehaviour     
{

    void Start()
    {
        Table tab = new Table(5, "CrispyWoody");       //makes Table using the class (works)
    }
}
```

Everything works and i have my table but I cant take information from it :(

```
void Start()
{

    int HeightOfTable = tab.TableHeight;         // this doesnt work

}
```

Any Help would be greatly appreaciated :D

Comment: So what's going wrong - what actually happens when you try to get 'HeightOfTable'? Do you get any error messages in the console? You have two start methods so I assume you're using two classes - how are refering to `tab`?

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is more with the way C# works. It has something called [access modifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/access-modifiers). The default level is [private](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/private) - meaning nothing outside the class can access it.

So solutions to your question is either make it public:

```
class Table() {    
    public int TableHeight;
    string TableName;

    Table(int _TableHeight, string _TableName) {  //constructor of class
        TableHeight = _TableHeight;
        TableName = _TableName;
    }
}
```

or crate a public getter method to access the value:

```
class Table() {
  int tableHeight;
  string tableName;

  Table(int _TableHeight, string _TableName) {
    tableHeight = _TableHeight;
    tableName = _TableName;
  }
  public int GetTableHeight() {
    return tableHeight;
  }
}
```

And after that you can access it like this:

```
class TableCreator : MonoBehaviour {
  private Table tab;
  void Awake() {
    tab = new Table(5, "CrispyWoody");
    int heightOfTable = tab.GetTableHeight();
  }
}
```

To avoid any confusion in the future, **always use** access modifiers.

Comment: Thank you a lot for helping me I knew about private and public but always thought it only mattered when trying to acess things from other scripts. But other scripts are ofc other classes.

Comment: You are trying to access it from another class, aren't you ? class TableCreator != class Table. Or am i getting something wrong ?